# Taylor series approximations of angular acceleration for a pendulum when the angle is small

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Angular acceleration of a pendulum is given by
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}= -\frac{mGR}{I}\sin(\theta)$$
How can we make a Taylor series approximation 5 terms when $\theta=0$?

This is for my computing class. 
Usually for taylor series, a function is sum of differenial and  factorials..

what about a taylor series for a second order diffenrtial equation?
what if the value of sin is not zero or near to zero?
I have tried searching internet to understand this

Comment: Write the series expansions for $\ddot \theta$ and for $\sin \theta$ around zero and equate the corresponding terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin\theta=\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\frac{\theta^7}{7!}+\frac{\theta^9}{9!}+...$$

Answer (score 1):

When $\theta$ approaches $0$, ([small angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation)) $\sin\theta$ can be expanded with the Taylor power series
$$\sin\theta=\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}+o(\theta^6)$$
Thus $\sin\theta$ can be replaced like this:
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}= -\frac{mGR}{I}\sin\theta=-\frac{mGR}{I}\left(\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}\right)$$